# Convert table name (in string) to use it in the LINQ query : C#, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of table names in form of strings. I want to loop through the list and use the table name in the LINQ query:

```
var db = new SomeContext();

// for a single table I can use the LINQ query as
var res = from q in db.Table
          where ......
          select q;
```

and it works just fine.

The above approach is hard coding. I need a generic solution for this to loop through multiple tables whose names are stored in a list.

```
// list of string containing table names
List<stringtableNames = [Get the table list from some source]
// not a problem here
```

loop through the table names and for each name execute a LINQ query as shown below

```
foreach(string table in tableNames)
{ 
    var queryRes = from t in table
                   where <some_condition>
                   select t; 
}
```

In the above statements "from t in table" above is not valid as "table" is a string. I need actual table object reference to use.

Need help on how do I go about doing that.

Comment: I thing You have to create a regular SQL query `"select * from " + table + "where ..."` in EF You can execute regular query

Comment: Does tables have same models ? If not its hard to get a result as entity model.

Comment: Well, what do you expect such a method to return? Obviously it can only return an object as you cannot provide the actual data-type nor even the table itself at compile-time. So I think you´re left on some kind of Sql-script where you set the table-name based on the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DbContext.Set method:

```
Set(System.Type.GetType("TableName"))
```

Above sentence will return a non generic DbSet. So, you will not be able to query with linq as usual. But you can use dynamic linq. ScottGu will [explain it better than me](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).
Please, check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/fe560b00-75ac-4d34-8171-d993c5651c0c/how-to-filtering-and-ordering-non-generic-dbset?forum=adodotnetentityframework) for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`select, where, from` is one way to define LINQ but You can use it if you have a list of elements (`IEnumerable<T>` for example), but You have only name of Your table

I  think  You have to create a regular SQL query

```
foreach(string table in tableNames)
{ 
  var query =$"select * from  {table} where <some_condition>"; 
  var list = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Obj>(query);
}
```

In EF You can execute regular query

Answer (score 0):

In **EF** you can execute **SQL Code**.

In this example i use EF with SQL (**String**)

```
var db = new SomeContext();
var list = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Obj>(Obj.sql);



class Obj
{
   public const string sql = @"select [tbl].[field] from [tbl]";
}
```